# Fallback value required for if array returns 0 values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm calculating a minimum value for the base of a graph output. One of my arrays are outputting a zero value thus not meeting the requirement and returning undefined.

```
const data =  [
    {value:0},
    {value:0},
    {value:0} ];

const defaultMinThreshold = 0;

const minThreshold = _.min([parseFloat(_.minBy(_(data).filter(d => d.value > 0).value(), 'value').value) - 0.5, defaultMinThreshold]);
```

If the data had any value larger than `0` e.g.

```
const data =  [
    {value:1},
    {value:0},
    {value:0} ];
```

This returns `minThreshold` as `0` - which is expected. I need it to return `0` instead of returning undefined when/if all the values are `0`.

I need to put a conditional in that searches data for values that at least has 1 value larger than 0 else return 0 by default.

JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0cps7q9j/

n.b As you can see I do filter the values to be `> 0`, I could do a `>= 0` but this lowers the base to 0 for arrays that could have a zero value in that data set so can't change this.

Reason for the filter is if the data had values of

```
const data =  [
        {value:4},
        {value:4},
        {value:3} ];
```

With above the minimum value would return 3, so the threshold would be 3 and the graph would start from 3 rather than zero.

Comment: You can always just append `|| 0` after all the logic, so if you get `undefined`, you'd actually get zero.

Comment: I did do that... if you do that on my fiddle its still undefined

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the filtering part. Does `const minThreshold = data.reduce((prev, curr) => Math.min(prev, curr.value), 0)` give you the desired result in each case?

Comment: hi @TomFenech I've mentioned more about the filter.

Comment: I'm curious, why did you subtract 0.5 from your parseFloat value?

Comment: @DropBearDan I'm curious why is `parseFloat` used at all - it's already a numeric value, not a string, so *at best* it's going to just give you the same value. It could also mangle the number for certain really big values. There is also a question of why do `_(data).filter(d => d.value > 0).value()` instead of simply `_.filter(data, d => d.value > 0)` which is the same way all other functions are called. Also, why put everything in one line, too. Why keep working with the entire objects instead of just the `value` number, as there is nothing object related used.

Comment: I'll be honest with you, I don't like using lodash at all since it tends to form very complicated sentences that pretends like it's efficient when it's not (although lodash does handle safe typings well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to completely use Lodash, here is something that is functional and readable. You could probably transform this into a pure Lodash solution as well if you like.

https://jsfiddle.net/0cps7q9j/11/

```
const data =  [
    {value:-1},
    {value:'0'},
    {value:1.234} ];

const defaultMinThreshold = 0;

  const filteredDataValueArray = data.filter(obj => !isNaN(parseFloat(obj.value)) && parseFloat(obj.value) >= 0).map(obj => obj.value);

    const minThreshold = _.min(filteredDataValueArray) || defaultMinThreshold;

console.log('filteredDataValueArray', filteredDataValueArray);
console.log('minThreshold', minThreshold);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, try values of 0 in all, comes back undefined where I need it to be 0

Comment: The link is now updated to reflect what I posted in the code: https://jsfiddle.net/0cps7q9j/11/ (btw the reason is _.min([]) === undefined by LODASH design, silly aye https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#min)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your code would be easier to understand written like this:

```
const values = data.map(d => d.value);
const hasNonZero = values.some(v => v > 0);
const minThreshold = hasNonZero ? _.min(values) : 0;
```

I'm only using lodash for the `_.min` which is convenient here. You could also replace this with `Math.min(...values)` or `Math.min.apply(null, values)`

---

#### Testing

```js
const dataSets = [
  [
   { value: 0 },
   { value: 0 },
   { value: 0 }
  ],
  [
   { value: 1 },
   { value: 0 },
   { value: 0 }
  ],
  [
   { value: 4 },
   { value: 4 },
   { value: 3 }
  ]
];

function getMinThreshold(data) {
  const values = data.map(d => d.value);
  const hasNonZero = values.some(v => v > 0);
  const minThreshold = hasNonZero ? Math.min(...values) : 0;
  return minThreshold;
}

dataSets.forEach(data => console.log(getMinThreshold(data)))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a lot cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Let's break up the logic to present better what's happening. I've extracted the code and broken up each operation on a separate line so it's easier to see:

```
const data =  [
    {value:0},
    {value:0},
    {value:0} ];

const defaultMinThreshold = 0;

const filterResult = _(data).filter(d => d.value > 0).value();
const minByResult = _.minBy(filterResult, 'value');
const minValue = minByResult.value;
const parsedValue = parseFloat(minValue);
const processedValue = parsedValue - 0.5;
const pair = [processedValue, defaultMinThreshold]

const minThreshold = _.min(pair);
```

First, I am going to address some problems and talk about some simplifications that can be done.

---

```
_(data).filter(d => d.value > 0).value()
```

This is a bit needless and also inconsistent with the other invocations of lodash. It's better to do `_.filter(data, d => d.value > 0)` - it's both shorter and consistent.

---

```
const filterResult = _(data).filter(d => d.value > 0).value();
const minByResult = _.minBy(filterResult, 'value');
const minValue = minByResult.value;
```

All three lines only work with the `value` property and finally extract the number from it. Since there is no need to keep working on objects, you can extract `value` and work with it directly. The entire section turns into

```
const mapResult = _.map(data, 'value');
const filterResult = _.filter(mapResult, d => d > 0);
const minValue = _.min(filterResult);
```

In addition the entire problem is with `minValue` - if you have an empty array and you try to use `_.min` or `_.minBy` on it, you would get `undefined`. I will come back to that.

---

```
const parsedValue = parseFloat(minValue);
```

This is unneeded. `minValue` would already be a number. JS has a single number type an it's already float - there is no "casting" from integer to float or vice versa. So, there is no need for parsing. The entire line can be removed.

---

```
const processedValue = minValue - 0.5;
```

So, knowing that `minValue` can be `undefined`, there are some things that can be done here to amend that. You can check for `undefined` perhaps by using a ternary `minValue ? minValue : 0 - 0.5` but I find it easier to always ensure you return a number from `_.min`, even if it tries to process an empty array.

```
const minValue = _.min(filterResult) || 0; //if the first value is falsey (undefined), return zero
const processedValue = minValue - 0.5; //you might end up with a result of -0.5
const clampedValue = _.clamp(processedValue, 0, Infinity); //ensures the value is [0,) - zero (inclusive) to unbound maxiumum
```

---

Putting all together you get

```js
const data =  [
    {value:0},
    {value:0},
    {value:0} ];

const defaultMinThreshold = 0;

const mapResult = _.map(data, 'value');
const filterResult = _.filter(mapResult, d => d > 0);
const minValue = _.min(filterResult) || 0;
const processedValue = minValue - 0.5;
const clampedValue = _.clamp(processedValue, 0, Infinity);
const pair = [clampedValue, defaultMinThreshold];

const minThreshold = _.min(pair);

console.log(minThreshold)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This is a bit verbose and uses a lot of variables only to pass them to the next function. You can cut them out in a couple of ways. First option is by using [chaining](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chain)

```js
const data =  [
    {value:0},
    {value:0},
    {value:0} ];

const defaultMinThreshold = 0;

var processedValue = _.chain(data)
  .map('value')
  .filter(d => d > 0)
  .sort()
  .take(1) //min() breaks the array chaining, so doing sort() -> take(1) ensures we can continue
  .map(x => x - 0.5) //not checking for "undefined" because an empty array won't be further processed
  .map(_.clamp) //the second and third argument to _clamp are optional and omitting them is the same as passing 0 and Infinity
  .value()[0];

//this will be undefined because we're getting index zero of an empty array
console.log("processedValue", processedValue); 

const pair = [processedValue, defaultMinThreshold];

//the minimum of undefined and zero is zero. So you don't need extra checks
const minThreshold = _.min(pair);

console.log("minThreshold", minThreshold)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

I left the `clamp` in this method but it might be unneeded. Since an array of zeroes is taken care of automatically, the only way you'd get a result of less than zero is if you have a minimum value of, say `0.3` so when you subtract `0.5` from it, you will end up with a negative. If that's not a possible input, you can omit the `clamp`.

The above will be operating on an array at all times until it finishes and gets the value. An alternative is to actually use `.min()` which, as I mentioned, breaks the array chaining, since it returns a single value. That means that you cannot use `.map()` any more which I personally find a bit inconsistent. Just to illustrate what happens then, here how to operate on a single value.

```js
const data =  [
    {value:0},
    {value:0},
    {value:0} ];

const defaultMinThreshold = 0;

var processedValue = _.chain(data)
  .map('value')
  .filter(d => d > 0)
  .min()
  .thru(x => x - 0.5) //if using .min() then you can use .thru to manipulate the single value
  .thru(_.clamp)
  .value();

//in this case, we get NaN because of undefined - 0.5
console.log("processedValue", processedValue); 

const pair = [processedValue, defaultMinThreshold];

//the minimum of NaN and zero is still zero
const minThreshold = _.min(pair);

console.log("minThreshold", minThreshold)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

Another way to achieve the same is doing a processing pipe of functions instead of operating on the value each time like with `_.chain`. This uses the [functional form of Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) for brevity but you can use normal Lodash if you pass functions through `_.rearg` and `_.curry`. At any rate, here is what this looks like:

```js
const data =  [
    {value:0},
    {value:0},
    {value:0} ];

const defaultMinThreshold = 0;

const processChain = _.flow( //compose all functions together
        _.map('value'),
        _.filter(d => d > 0),
        _.min,
        x => x || 0,
        x => x - 0.5,
        _.clamp(0)(Infinity)
      );

const processedValue = processChain(data);

console.log("processedValue", processedValue)

const pair = [processedValue, defaultMinThreshold];

const minThreshold = _.min(pair);

console.log("minThreshold", minThreshold)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```

This is actually very much closer in intent to how both your code worked and my initial breakdown. The way `_.flow` works it to make essentially the following

```
aResult = a(input);
bResult = b(aResult)
cResult = c(bResult)
```

and so on, with the exception that it defines the *process*, you can then later supply `input` which will, in turn, be subsequently passed around.

Answer (score 0):

A concise way with lodash by using [`_.minBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#minBy):

```js
const data = [ [ { value: 0 }, { value: 0 }, { value: 0 } ], [ { value: 1 }, { value: 0 }, { value: 0 } ], [ { value: 4 }, { value: 4 }, { value: 3 } ] ];

const result = _.map(data, x => _.minBy(x, 'value').value)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```